# Find number of multiple duplicate div in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in my code that replicates the jqueryUI dialog (it seems many people are having issues with this). The `div` with dialog id is being wrapped with a `div` with `class='ui-dialog...'` like this:

```
<div class='ui-dialog...' >
    <div id='dialogId'

<div class='ui-dialog...' >
    <div id='dialogId'
```

What I want to do is to keep track of the number of `div`s with similar id. I tried

`$('#dialogId').length`

but it always return 1 even though Chrome Dev Tools shows multiple DOM copies (except the style of the first is `display: none` and the second is `display: block`). I guess the selector is returning within the enclosing parent `div` that's why its always `.length = 1`. How do I go about counting the number of parent `div`'s (whose `class` is equivalent to `ui-dialog`) and the child `div`s id equivalent to `dialogId` using the `dialogId` as the selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
$(function(){

  console.log( 'Wrong: ' + $('#dialog').length );
  console.log( 'Correct: ' + $('div#dialog').length );
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zevupaluri/1/watch?html,js,console)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. For other answers, I appreciate your inputs, haven't tried your solutions because this one's the shortest so I tried it first and it worked for me already.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `filter()`: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p6fg79qx/)**

```
var duplicated= $('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id')=='dialogId';
}).length;
alert(duplicated);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
var count=0;
$("div").each(function(index,element){
    if($(this).is("#dialogId")){
        count=count+1; // or whatever code you want
    }
});
```

here a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hpawe0m7/)

hope this will help you